# Пропадают ссылки в фрагменте

Tags: android

У меня есть фрагмент (только основные участки кода):

```
public class PageWords extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView = null;
    private RecyclerWordsAdapter mAdapter = null;
    private Handler handler;
    private View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table, null);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.table_recyclerView);
        mAdapter = new RecyclerWordsAdapter(mListFormOne, mListFormTwo, this);
        handler = new Handler();

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        Log.i(TAG, MSG + "MAIN HASH CODE 1 = " + ((MainActivity) getActivity()).hashCode());
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG, MSG + "MAIN HASH CODE 2 = " + ((MainActivity) getActivity()).hashCode());

        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).startLoad();
    }

    public void resumeLists(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listOne, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listTwo) {
        mListFormOne = listOne;
        mListFormTwo = listTwo;

        Log.i(TAG, MSG + "MAIN HASH CODE 3 = " + ((MainActivity) getActivity()).hashCode());
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

И активность (приводить весь `AsyncTask` не стал, так как он большой и тут он не нужен):

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

        private ViewPager viewPager;
        private PageWords pageWords;
        private LoadData loadData;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            pageWords = new PageWords();

            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_viewPager_1);
            //В адаптере создаются страницы из pageWords и двух пустых фрагментов
            MyFragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
            viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
            viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

            Log.i(TAG, MSG + "MAIN THIS HASH CODE 1 = " + this.hashCode());
        }

        public void startLoad() {
            try {
                loadData = (LoadData) getLastCustomNonConfigurationInstance();
            } catch (Exception e) { Log.i(TAG, MSG + "ERROR on get" }

            if (loadData == null) {
                loadData = new LoadData(name);
                loadData.link(this);
                loadData.execute();
            } else {
                loadData.link(this);
                pageWords.resumeLists(loadData.getListOne(), loadData.getListTwo());

                try {
                    loadData.resume();
                } catch (Exception e) { Log.i(TAG, MSG + "ERROR on resume"); }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Object onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance() {
            loadData.unLink();
            loadData.pause();

            return loadData;
        }

        private class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>> {

            ...
            ...
            ...

        }
    }
```

Проблема в том, что фрагмент "теряет" все ссылки и активность после метода `onActivityCreated`. В `onCreateView` и `onActivityCreated` все хорошо, но когда начинает выполняться `onStart` и `resumeLists` — все ссылки становятся `null` и перестает работать метод `getActivity`, соответственно `resumeLists` не может обратиться к адаптеру и вылетает `NPE`. Исходя из хэш-кода (`this.hashCode`) — в `onCreateView` и `onActivityCreated` он один, а в `resumeLists` уже другой! В чем моя ошибка и почему так происходит!? P.S. Ошибка выскакивает только после поворота экрана, так как без поворота ничего, кроме `onCreateView` не запускается.

---

Лог при первом запуске активности (без ошибок):

```
12-07 22:15:44.458    9876-9876/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MAIN THIS HASH CODE 1 = 17820220
12-07 22:15:44.485    9876-9876/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MAIN HASH CODE 1 = 17820220
12-07 22:15:44.486    9876-9876/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MAIN HASH CODE 2 = 17820220
```

Лог при втором запуске активности (поворот экрана):

```
12-07 22:18:59.225    9876-9876/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MAIN THIS HASH CODE 1 = 264979963
12-07 22:18:59.229    9876-9876/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MAIN HASH CODE 1 = 264979963
12-07 22:18:59.229    9876-9876/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary I/myApplication﹕ MAIN HASH CODE 2 = 264979963
```

И стэктрейс ошибки:

```
12-07 22:18:59.240    9876-9876/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary, PID: 9876
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Object.hashCode()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4203)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:178)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1476)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5624)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Object.hashCode()' on a null object reference
            at com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary.fragments.PageWords.resumeLists(PageWords.java:71)
            at com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary.MainActivity.startLoad(MainActivity.java:88)
            at com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary.fragments.PageWords.onActivityCreated(PageWords.java:64)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1970)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1051)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1207)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1189)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2001)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:165)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:507)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1244)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6108)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2478)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4203)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:178)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1476)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5624)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Comment: А почему вы инфлейтите разметку откуда то из .. эээ .. другого места, а не из передаваемого в метод `inflater` ? Перопределения метода `onStart()` в фрагменте что то не видно. При повороте активити создается заново - совершенно другая активити

Comment: @pavlofff, хм... То что я инфлейтирую не то - не заметил, исправлю. А метод `onStart` был только, чтобы посмотреть на лог. То что создается другая активность я знаю.

Comment: @pavlofff, я вопрос дополнил (добавил логи и исправил `inflater`).

Comment: @pavlofff, помогите, пожалуйста — http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97341/

Comment: Похоже до вызова resumeLists происходит поворот экрана, активити создается заново, а объект pageWords создан в прошлой активити и был связан тоже с прошлой активити. Иначе не объяснить почему getActivity() возвращает null.

Comment: @hardsky, но почему так и почему переменные null?

Comment: @bukashka101 До вызова resumeLists вы повернули устройство, pageWords связан с прошлой активити, ее больше не существует.

Comment: @bukashka101 вот код из активити     `final public FragmentActivity getActivity() {
        return mHost == null ? null : (FragmentActivity) mHost.getActivity();
    }`

Comment: @bukashka101 не стану утверждать, что тут прям все очевидно из лога. Но вы упомянули поворот и пересоздание активити, в логе есть строчка подозрительная handleRelaunchActivity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Практически стандартный паттерн в Android-разработке - MVC (Model - View - Controller). При этом активити(фрагмент) выполняет роль контроллера, она не должна выполнять работу модели - производить какие то манипуляции с данными и содержать в себе методы по их обработке, только направить их на View и регистрировать взаимодействие с пользователем.

В вашем случае размещать код по обработке данных в активити, и тем более создавать там какие то методы по их извлечению, в корне неправильно (да, так делается во всяких простейших примерах для упрощения, но в реальной разработке это неприемлемо).

Вам следует создать отдельный класс, который не будет наследоваться и зависить ни от каких классов с жизненным циклом, вроде активити, а будет заниматься исключительно предоставлением данных по требованию.

Запрашивать данные должен тот, кто в них нуждается, в вашем случае - фрагмент, но никак не активити. Активити в этом процессе вовсе не должна участвовать, она лишь хостит фрагменты и манипулирует ими при необходимости.

В общем вам нужно серьезно улучшить свои знания по общим принципам архитектуры приложений, а так же по самой концепции ООП. Сейчас вы пытаетесь заново пройти то, что уже давно прройдено и решено - через ошибки, пробы и страдания, которые сейчас испытываете вы, совершенно напрасно.